# Center Widget in Transform.translate

Tags: flutter

How can I position a Widget in the center of a `Transform.translate`?

That is MyWidget `size/2` at the point - so that the widget's center is at the point `Offset(100, 100)`

```
return Transform.translate(
  offset: Offset(100, 100),
  child: const MyWidget());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can mix and match [Positioned] and [FractionalTranslation].
If you combine the two with a code like :

```
Positioned(
left: childWidget.x,
top: childWidget.y,
child: FractionalTranslation(
    translation: Offset(-0.5, -0.5),
    child: childWidget,
));
```

[1](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
Container(
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: const MyWidget())
```

Might have the desired effect, though it will come with empty space around it